# Suddenly can't connect to Windows 7 PC from XBMC

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, kodi, xbox360

I have XBMC installed on a soft-modded classic Xbox and all of a sudden I cannot connect to the shared folders on my Windows 7 PC. Well, it can connect but it wants a username and password, but none exist on my computer.

It's been several weeks since I last used it, but it was working fine then! and no particular changes I can think of aside from I guess a few Windows updates.
I've seen reference online to Windows Live essentials causing issues with file sharing, but I don't even have that installed. And I made sure to tick 'turn off password protected sharing' in my advanced network setup.

I had the guest account turned off and working fine before, and tried turning it on but no luck.

I can access my shared folders fine from other Computers and a PS3.

I've read a couple threads of similar situations on various folders and none of their solutions have worked.

Comment: Do you have the samba shares on xbmc

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but the "Turn off Password protected sharing" change worked for me.